# Travis CI and Grunt Error: Grunt build failed and exited with 99 during '.'

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, travis-ci

I am trying to integrate Travis CI with a repository(forked on github). Everything is fine but Travis CI website is showing the following error under Job.

```
Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
The command "grunt build" failed and exited with 99 during .
```

I have added npm install in my `.travis.yml` and also defined script in my `package.json` file.
The grunt dependencies and gruntfile.js has also been properly set up.

Comment: What version of grunt is it? Can you edit with your `.travis.yml` and scripts in `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Unable to find local grunt.
```

Is pretty explicit. Just add grunt to the dependencies of your package.json or run

```
npm i --save grunt
```

*EDIT*: OP's problem was actually due to a missing `package.json` at the root of the project.

Comment: Grunt is already in the dependencies of my package.json:

` "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-nodemon": "~0.2.0"
},`

I have also added npm install in my .travis.yml file:

`before_install: npm install -g grunt-cli
install: npm install
before_script: grunt build
script: grunt travis
`
thanks,
Apurva Nagar

Comment: It is in the `devDependencies`. Add it to the normal `dependencies` as well.

Comment: I also see the following error during `npm install` :

`npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/travis/build/Apurva-Nagar/Tracker/package.json'

npm WARN Tracker No description
npm WARN Tracker No repository field.
npm WARN Tracker No README data
npm WARN Tracker No license field.`

But I don't really know how to fix this, any ideas?

Comment: This simply means your `package.json` could not be found. Is it at the root of your project? If I go to your [GitHub project page](https://github.com/Apurva-Nagar/Tracker), I see that no. You need a `package.json` at the root of the project.

Comment: New errors, I really don't know what went wrong.  see errors --> [errors](http://imgur.com/a/jYKLU)

Comment: The error is pretty explicit, the JSON of `package.json` is not valid. You forgot a comma.